# I need to read a file until "over" is encountered

Tags: c

I have trouble reading a file until a word is encountered, this is what I have done but I don't think the if statement allows strings to be written within them

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

  int i;
  char buffer[100];
  FILE *fptr = fopen("testing.txt", "r");
  if(fptr != NULL)
    printf("file opened successfully\n");
  else {
    printf("file error occured\n");
    printf("terminating program...\n");
    return 0;
  }

  while (fgets(buffer, 100,fptr))
  {
    if(buffer != "over") {
      printf("%s ", buffer);
    }
    else
      return 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i tried that just now, doesnt work..

Comment: Please show the actual input as last line.

Comment: @BLUEPIXYthis is the contents of text file, (there is a newline after first over): how are you over
i am busy over

Comment: I do not see often new line is a comment. Try to add to the question.

Comment: You need another check the end of the string is if over.

Comment: _(there is a newline after first over): how are you over i am busy over_ do you want print `"how are you "`?

Comment: yes @BLUEPIXY , i also want to know how i would everything except the two "over"s

Comment: _two "over"_ By coming out of the loop when one is found?

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
if(buffer != "over")
```

you compare two pointers, the pointer to `buffer` and the pointer to the string literal `"over"`. Those pointers will never be the same.

To compare strings in C you have to use the [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) function.

Comment: i edited the if statement to "if(strcmp(buffer, "over") != 0)" its still reading the over.. @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: @user3151918 You have to remember that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) leaves the newline (if one was read) in the buffer, so either you have to compare with a string containing a newline or remove the newline from the buffer. Optionally you can use [`strncmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) to compare only the first four characters.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg i edited my if statement again to: if((strncmp(buffer, "over\n",4)) != 0) doesnt work!

Comment: @user3151918 It seems that you are reading lines that contains *more* than the single word `"over"`. `fgets` reads the complete line into the buffer, if you want to check and print words you have to [tokenize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) the line after you read it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think strncmp that's inappropriate. _compare only the first four characters_

Answer (score 0):

For comparing string you need to use `strcmp()` function. You can't do directly by `if(buffer != "over")`. It compares pointers instead of stings.

Comment: i edited my if statement to if((strncmp(buffer, "over\n",4)) != 0) still doesnt work, any ideas?

Comment: What about contents of testing.txt?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isEndWith(const char *string, const char *word){
    int len = strlen(string);
    int lenw = strlen(word);
    if(len >= lenw)
        return strncmp(string + len - lenw, word, lenw)==0;//or use strcmp
    else 
        return 0;
}

int main(void){
    char str1[] = "how are you over i am busy over\n";
    char str2[] = "how are you over i am busy over\n";
    char *p;
    if(p=strchr(str1, '\n'))
        *p = '\0';//chomp \n
    if(!isEndWith(str1, "over"))//check case end string
        printf("%s", str1);
    else {
        int len = strlen(str1);
        str1[len - 4] = '\0';// 4 : strlen("over");
        printf("%s\n", str1);//print "how are you over i am busy \n"
    }
    if(p=strstr(str2, "over"))//check case contain string
        *p = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", str2);//print "how are you \n"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can u elaborate on "returnstrncmp(string+len - len1,word,lenw) == 0" please

Comment: @user3151918 It compares the word that it specified at the end of the string.

Comment: @user3151918 `string + len - lenw` meant `'&string[len-lenw]`.